# Android HCE issue

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I'm working on my NFC-HCE project for Android. I stuck into a problem that my app doesn't recognize APDU SELECT Query.

I'm using ACL122U reader powered by chrome-nfc with Forum Type 4 support and APDU_SELECT query goes like *00A4040007F039414848483500*. I checked it many time, there can't be error in AID. I tried to change several times, I found the working app on the Net which was working when I changed AID in my chrome-nfc. I guess there is something about manifest problem or service launching problem. I will appreciate any help.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".myHostApduService" 
                 android:exported="true"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                       android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
        </service>
```

**ApduService.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/servicedesc"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
    <aid-group android:description="@string/aiddescription"
        android:category="other">

        <aid-filter android:name="F0394148484835"/>
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>
```

**myHostApduService.java**

```
public class myHostApduService extends HostApduService {

    private static final String TAG = "myHostApduService";


    //
    private static final byte[] APDU_SELECT = {
            (byte)0x00, // CLA  - Class - Class of instruction
            (byte)0xA4, // INS  - Instruction - Instruction code
            (byte)0x04, // P1   - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
            (byte)0x00, // P2   - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
            (byte)0x07, // Lc field - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            (byte)0xF0, (byte)0x39, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x48, (byte)0x48, (byte)0x48, (byte)0x35, // NDEF Tag Application name
            (byte)0x00  // Le field - Maximum number of bytes expected in the data field of the response to the command
    };

    private static final byte[] CAPABILITY_CONTAINER = {
            (byte)0x00, // CLA  - Class - Class of instruction
            (byte)0xa4, // INS  - Instruction - Instruction code
            (byte)0x00, // P1   - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
            (byte)0x0c, // P2   - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
            (byte)0x02, // Lc field - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            (byte)0xe1, (byte)0x03 // file identifier of the CC file
    };

    private static final byte[] READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER = {
            (byte)0x00, // CLA  - Class - Class of instruction
            (byte)0xb0, // INS  - Instruction - Instruction code
            (byte)0x00, // P1   - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
            (byte)0x00, // P2   - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
            (byte)0x0f  // Lc field - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
    };

    // In the scenario that we have done a CC read, the same byte[] match
    // for ReadBinary would trigger and we don't want that in succession
    private boolean READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false;

    private static final byte[] READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE = {
            (byte)0x00, (byte)0x0F, // CCLEN length of the CC file
            (byte)0x20, // Mapping Version 2.0
            (byte)0x00, (byte)0x3B, // MLe maximum 59 bytes R-APDU data size
            (byte)0x00, (byte)0x34, // MLc maximum 52 bytes C-APDU data size
            (byte)0x04, // T field of the NDEF File Control TLV
            (byte)0x06, // L field of the NDEF File Control TLV
            (byte)0xE1, (byte)0x04, // File Identifier of NDEF file
            (byte)0x00, (byte)0x32, // Maximum NDEF file size of 50 bytes
            (byte)0x00, // Read access without any security
            (byte)0x00, // Write access without any security
            (byte)0x90, (byte)0x00 // A_OKAY
    };

    private static final byte[] NDEF_SELECT = {
            (byte)0x00, // CLA  - Class - Class of instruction
            (byte)0xa4, // Instruction byte (INS) for Select command
            (byte)0x00, // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
            (byte)0x0c, // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
            (byte)0x02, // Lc field - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            (byte)0xE1, (byte)0x04 // file identifier of the NDEF file retrieved from the CC file
    };

    private static final byte[] NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN = {
            (byte)0x00, // Class byte (CLA)
            (byte)0xb0, // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
            (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, // Parameter byte (P1, P2), offset inside the CC file
            (byte)0x02  // Le field
    };

    private static final byte[] NDEF_READ_BINARY_GET_NDEF = {
            (byte)0x00, // Class byte (CLA)
            (byte)0xb0, // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
            (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, // Parameter byte (P1, P2), offset inside the CC file
            (byte)0x0f  //  Le field
    };

    private static final byte[] A_OKAY = {
            (byte)0x90,  // SW1 Status byte 1 - Command processing status
            (byte)0x00   // SW2 Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
    };

    private static final byte[] NDEF_ID = {
            (byte)0xE1,
            (byte)0x04
    };

    private NdefRecord NDEF_URI = new NdefRecord(
            NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
            NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,
            NDEF_ID,
            "Hello world, bitch!".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
    );
    private byte[] NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray();
    private byte[] NDEF_URI_LEN = BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.length).toByteArray();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (intent.hasExtra("ndefMessage")) {
            NDEF_URI = new NdefRecord(
                    NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
                    NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,
                    NDEF_ID,
                    intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
            );

            NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray();
            NDEF_URI_LEN = BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.length).toByteArray();

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Your NDEF text has been set!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand() | NDEF" + NDEF_URI.toString());

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {

        //
        // The following flow is based on Appendix E "Example of Mapping Version 2.0 Command Flow"
        // in the NFC Forum specification
        //
        Log.i(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | incoming commandApdu: " + utils.bytesToHex(commandApdu));

        //
        // First command: NDEF Tag Application select (Section 5.5.2 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (utils.isEqual(APDU_SELECT, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "APDU_SELECT triggered. Our Response: " + utils.bytesToHex(A_OKAY));
            return A_OKAY;
        }

        //
        // Second command: Capability Container select (Section 5.5.3 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (utils.isEqual(CAPABILITY_CONTAINER, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "CAPABILITY_CONTAINER triggered. Our Response: " + utils.bytesToHex(A_OKAY));
            return A_OKAY;
        }

        //
        // Third command: ReadBinary data from CC file (Section 5.5.4 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (utils.isEqual(READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER, commandApdu) && !READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER triggered. Our Response: " + utils.bytesToHex(READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE));
            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = true;
            return READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE;
        }

        //
        // Fourth command: NDEF Select command (Section 5.5.5 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (utils.isEqual(NDEF_SELECT, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_SELECT triggered. Our Response: " + utils.bytesToHex(A_OKAY));
            return A_OKAY;
        }

        //
        // Fifth command:  ReadBinary, read NLEN field
        //
        if (utils.isEqual(NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN, commandApdu)) {

            byte[] start = {
                    (byte)0x00
            };

            // Build our response
            byte[] response = new byte[start.length + NDEF_URI_LEN.length + A_OKAY.length];

            System.arraycopy(start, 0, response, 0, start.length);
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, response, start.length, NDEF_URI_LEN.length);
            System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, start.length + NDEF_URI_LEN.length, A_OKAY.length);

            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN triggered. Our Response: " + utils.bytesToHex(response));

            return response;
        }

        //
        // Sixth command: ReadBinary, get NDEF data
        //
        if (utils.isEqual(NDEF_READ_BINARY_GET_NDEF, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | NDEF_READ_BINARY_GET_NDEF triggered");

            byte[] start = {
                    (byte)0x00
            };

            // Build our response
            byte[] response = new byte[start.length + NDEF_URI_LEN.length + NDEF_URI_BYTES.length + A_OKAY.length];

            System.arraycopy(start, 0, response, 0, start.length);
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, response, start.length, NDEF_URI_LEN.length);
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_BYTES, 0, response, start.length + NDEF_URI_LEN.length, NDEF_URI_BYTES.length);
            System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, start.length + NDEF_URI_LEN.length + NDEF_URI_BYTES.length, A_OKAY.length);

            Log.i(TAG, NDEF_URI.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY_GET_NDEF triggered. Our Response: " + utils.bytesToHex(response));

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "NDEF text has been sent to the reader!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();

            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false;
            return response;
        }

        //
        // We're doing something outside our scope
        //
        Log.wtf(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | I don't know what's going on!!!.");
        return "Can I help you?".getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDeactivated() Fired! Reason: " + reason);
    }
}
```

**sendOverNfcActivity.java**

```
public class sendOverNFCActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String TAG = "sendOverNFCActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sendnfc);






        Button setNdef = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_ndef_button);
        setNdef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View view) {

                                           //
                                           // Technically, if this is past our byte limit,
                                           // it will cause issues.
                                           //
                                           // TODO: add validation
                                           //
                                           TextView getNdefString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ndef_text);
                                           String test = getNdefString.getText().toString();

                                           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myHostApduService.class);
                                           intent.putExtra("ndefMessage", test);
                                           startService(intent);
                                       }
                                   }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

The problem is that `public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras)` never runs and app sending 6a82 every time in response that mean file/app was not found. I totally can't understand why this happens even if AID is correct.

Comment: So you are sure that the reader side actually uses that AID in the select command? I.e. that it sends `00A4040007F039414848483500`? What code are you using on the reader side? WHat Android device do you use? Does it support HCE? What's output by adb logcat (not just for your app but for the whole system) when you send the select command?

Comment: Hi, Michael. Yes, I`m absolutely sure it sends this code. I veryfied it through JS-console output. My Android device - Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini, it was successfully working with examples from android.developer. On reader side i`m using app of justin ribiero. https://github.com/justinribeiro/hce-to-chromenfc-app

Comment: 6-19 15:59:52.125   1268-19632/? D/HostEmulationManager﹕ Dropping non-select APDU in STATE_W4_SELECT
06-19 15:59:52.155   1268-19632/? D/HostEmulationManager﹕ notifyHostEmulationData
06-19 15:59:52.155   1268-19632/? D/HostEmulationManager﹕ call findSelectAid - 1

Comment: When you get the error message "Dropping non-select APDU in STATE_W4_SELECT", you should also get statusword 6F00, so that error message should not really be caused by your SELECT APDU. The statusword 6A82 clearly indicates that the Android device received a syntactically valid SELECT by AID command but that it did not find the AID. Hence, the AID sent by your chrome-nfc app must be a different one than the one that the Android side expects.

Comment: Btw. the chrome-nfc example that you linked uses the AID `F0394148148100` and **not** `F0394148484835`.

Comment: I changed the AID in example of course:) I don`t know why, but when I created new project for my android app it started working nice... The only difference - now i`m using gradle